# Difference between storing files in public directory and in storage in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

What's the difference between storing files (images) in `public/images` folder and storing them in `storage/app/public`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Public folder means files will be publicly accessible. For example an image stored in `public/images/my-image.jpeg` can be viewed by anyone by going to

`mysite.com/images/my-image.jpeg`

However, files stored in `storage` directory are only available to your app.

Laravel has a `php artisan storage:link` command that adds a symlink to `public` from `storage/app/public`

The reason for this is that your `storage` may not be your local filesystem, but rather an Amazon S3 bucket or a Rackspace CDN (or anything else)

You will need to setup your filesystem configurations by following the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem

Once this is done you can get/store files to/from the storage place rather than have everything on your server.

There are 2 helper methods for `public` and `storage` to show files:

storage: `storage_path('my-file.jpg')`

public: `asset('my-file.jpg')`

Answer (score 10):

The `public/images` is a webroot directory. This means that it can be accessed via a web browser `mozilla, chrome, etc...`

The `storage/app/public` is a folder for `cache`, `logs`.

**Where to place my files?**

Rule of thumb: If you need to control who can view those files put them in `storage/app/public` otherwise put them in `public/images`

**EDIT**

As other answers pointed out the `public` webroot directory any user can see it. Even non logged users

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/storage-v-public-folder) and was answered stating:

> public is a "WEBROOT" directory. it consists of files which can be
>   accessed from a browser. There is your `index.php` file, which take a
>   role of your enter point. Also your `css`, `javascript` files there.
>
> `storage` is a folder for cache, logs etc.