# Symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public still makes the files in the storage directory accessible from the web

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem

**What I have done**

When I researched about storing files in laravel. I came across two approaches.

1. Storing the assets directly inside the public folder.
2. Creating a symbolic link from `public/storage` to
   `storage/app/public`

When I researched about which one two use, I came across this stack overflow link.  [Difference between storing files in public directory and in storage in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297777/difference-between-storing-files-in-public-directory-and-in-storage-in-laravel-5)
In this link in the top answer it was mentioned,

> Public folder means files will be publicly accessible.
>
> For example an image stored in
> `public/images/my-image.jpeg`can be viewed by anyone by
> going to `mysite.com/images/my-image.jpeg`
>
> However, files stored in storage directory are only available to your
> app.

Since, including in the mentioned stack overflow post above, and many other posts I have read on different platforms implied the fact that files in the `public` directory are web accessible whereas the files inside the `storage` directory are not, I tried to test this by storing files both in the `public` directory and in the `storage` directory one at a time, and then checking if the files are accessible through the web url.

My attempts went as below,

1. First I added the path `images/` in the public
   directory and placed some images (Let us say
   `test1.jpg`, `test2.jpg` and
   `test3.jpg`) into that directory. Then inside my blade
   template for the `src` attribute of my
   `img` tags I referred to them as
   `URL('images/test1.jpg')` etc... and they were indeed
   rendered on the webpage. Then I also tried to access the images from
   the url by going to
   `http://localhost:8000/images/test.jpg`. The result was
   as expected, **The images were rendered on the web page + they were
   accessible from the url**
2. Then I ran the command `php artisan storage:link`
   on the console, which according to the articles I read, should
   create a `symbolic link` between the directories
   `public/storage` and `storage/app/public`.
   As soon as I ran the command, I got a new folder called
   `storage` created in the `public`
   directory. Then I moved all my images to that
   `public/storage` directory. Then set the
   `src` attribute my `img` tags as
   `URL('storage/test1.img')` etc... the images were
   rendered on the web page. Then I tried to check if the images are
   still accessible from the url. for that on the url bar I went to
   `http://localhost:8000/storage/test1.jpg`. **The
   images were STILL ACCESSIBLE from the url.**

**Problem**

However, according to the answer I have mentioned and some other similar links, I expected those images to not be accessible from the url in the 2) above since the images should now be actually in the `storage/app/public` which we have created a symbolic link to from `public/storage`. (Files inside the `storage` directory should not be publicly accessible right?)


This led me to two questions,

1. **Why are the images are still being accessible from the url even after I created a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` and stored the images in the `public/storage` directory?**
2. **As happened with my case, if the files in the
   `public/storage` are still accessible through the web
   url, what are the advantages of actually creating the symbolic link?
   It does not seem to offer any more security since the files are
   still accessible from the url.**

It would be really helpful if anyone can help me understand the answers to the above two questions I have. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening to you is the expected behavior.

The purpose of Laravel storage is to interact with your local files and make use of Laravel helpers, besides being easily shared across deployments.
Saying that I would avoid moving your files directly to your public folder.

On the other hand, by adding files to your `storage/app/public` folder you are assuming that those files will be publicly accessible, but they won't be until you create a symbolic link which is a special kind of file that points to another file.
When you create a symbolic link you are saying "hey, if the user reaches `http://localhost:8000/storage/` just show the files stored in `storage/app/public`"

So if you want private files (and you have created a symbolic link) just don't upload them to your `storage/app/public` folder, instead of that put your private files out from the public folder such as `storage/app/myfiles`

He are your answers:

> 1 - Why are the images are still being accessible from the url even
> after I created a symbolic link from public/storage to
> storage/app/public and stored the images in the public/storage
> directory?

Because in fact, you have created a symbolic link for that purpose, making the `storage/app/public` publicly accessible.

> 2 - As happened with my case, if the files in the public/storage are
> still accessible through the web url, what are the advantages of
> actually creating the symbolic link? It does not seem to offer any
> more security since the files are still accessible from the url.

As said, the advantage is to make use of Laravel filesystem. The public link doesn't determine the privacy of your files

Answer (score 0):

You might have many different types of files in one project. Some are accessible to the public, like images embedded in a website (as your example shows), and some are private files, let's say, for example, a pdf of a private report.

Any file that is accessible to the public can be stored in either storage/public or directly in public. As you have observed, no difference there since the former would have a symlink established.

However, private files cannot be stored storage/public (if symlink is established) and especially not directly in public folder for obvious reasons.

Those files can go in storage/app/NOT_PUBLIC_REPO. These files should be made accessible via protected routes (along with signed routes if you want extra protection).